Pixel 9 Pro: Any way to record video with both wide-angle and normal lens? (both back-facing)
I want to produce two video files of the same scene, one taken with the wide-angle lens and one taken with the normal lens. Using a Pixel 9 Pro.
Is there any way to achieve that?
I am OK with rooting, and developing if really needed.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager#getConcurrentCameraIds() returns {{0, 1}} which makes me think it might be possible.

When I split the screen and use two third-party cameras, one stops showing live preview as soon as I start the other one.
Questions on this topic (1, 2, 3) conclude that it depends on the model, hence my model-specific question. Full info shown by Open Camera:
Open Camera v1.53.1
Code: 90
Package: net.sourceforge.opencamera
Android API version: 35
Device manufacturer: Google
Device model: Pixel 9 Pro
Display size: 960x1935
Display metrics: 960x1935
Current camera ID: 0
No. of cameras: 2
Multi-camera?: false
Camera API: Camera2 (Android L)
Camera orientation: 90
Photo mode: HDR
Min zoom factor: 0.51
Max zoom factor: 30.0
Preview resolutions: 1920x960, 1280x960, 1280x720, 1024x768, 1024x576, 800x600, 720x480, 640x480, 640x360, 352x288, 320x240, 176x144
Preview resolution: 1280x960
Photo resolutions: 4080x3072, 4032x3024, 4000x3000, 4032x2268, 3840x2160, 4000x2000, 3264x2448, 3264x1836, 2560x1920, 2688x1512, 1920x1920, 2560x1280, 2048x1536, 1920x1440, 1920x1080
Photo resolution: 4080x3072
Video qualities: 1, 6_r4000x2000, 6_r3264x1836, 6_r2560x1920, 6_r2688x1512, 6_r1920x1920, 6_r2560x1280, 6_r2048x1536, 6_r1920x1440, 6, 5_r1600x1200, 5_r1920x960, 5_r1792x1008, 5_r1440x1080, 5_r1344x1008, 5_r1280x960, 5_r1080x1080, 5, 4_r1024x768, 4_r1024x576, 4_r800x600, 4, 3_r640x480, 3_r640x360, 3, 7, 2
Video resolutions: 3840x2160, 4000x2000, 3264x1836, 2560x1920, 2688x1512, 1920x1920, 2560x1280, 2048x1536, 1920x1440, 1920x1080, 1600x1200, 1920x960, 1792x1008, 1440x1080, 1344x1008, 1280x960, 1080x1080, 1280x720, 1024x768, 1024x576, 800x600, 720x480, 640x480, 640x360, 352x288, 320x240, 176x144
Video quality: 6
Video frame width: 1920
Video frame height: 1080
Video bit rate: 33000000
Video frame rate: 60
Video capture rate: 60.0
Video high speed: false
Video capture rate factor: 1.0
Auto-level?: Available
Auto-level enabled?: false
Face detection?: Available
RAW?: Available
HDR?: Available
Panorama?: Available
Gyro sensors?: Available
Expo?: Available
Expo compensation?: Available
Exposure compensation range: -24 to 24
Manual ISO?: Available
ISO range: 22 to 11277
Manual exposure?: Available
Exposure range: 26345 to 500000000
Manual WB?: Available
WB temperature: 1000 to 15000
Optical stabilization?: Available
Optical stabilization enabled?: true
Video stabilization?: Available
Video stabilization enabled?: false
Tonemap curve?: Available
Tonemap max curve points: 65
Can disable shutter sound?: Available
Camera view angle: 70.71637 , 53.671764
Flash modes: flash_off, flash_auto, flash_on, flash_torch
Focus modes: focus_mode_auto, focus_mode_macro, focus_mode_locked, focus_mode_infinity, focus_mode_manual2, focus_mode_edof, focus_mode_continuous_picture, focus_mode_continuous_video
Color effects: None
Scene modes: auto, night, portrait
White balances: auto, manual, incandescent, fluorescent, warm-fluorescent, daylight, cloudy-daylight, twilight, shade
Magnetic accuracy?: 1
Using SAF?: false
Save Location: OpenCamera
Save Location SAF: 
Parameters: None


To prevent "spy apps" I believe that only one app is allowed access to the camera APIs at a time. Recent version of Android do support multi-camera operation. You may want to install/run Open Camera from F-Droid In Open Camera, gear icon, scroll down to 'About' and then copy from clipboard the debug/device results into your question. There should be an entry called 'Multicamera?'

@MorrisonChang: Thanks! Pasted. It says Multi-camera?: false... is there any way to modify this?

Related StackOverflow: Opening Second Camera with Camera2 Multicamera API. After reading that to me Its unclear to me if a 'false' there just means just strictly sticking to the Camera2 APIs. You may want to try Camera2 API Probe but theSO link really points out the limitations that may exist in the camera pipeline.

@MorrisonChang I ran Camera2 API Probe, and in Available capabilities I see LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA.

If you read the docs, LOGICAL can be fusion of multiple physical cameras. I have a Pixel 6a which has a regular & wide camera on the back, that app reports similar. Hopefully someone has attempted what you are seeking and state what is possible. Should you wish to try, I would look at: https://github.com/ananthrajsingh/front-rear-simultaneous-camera as a starting project and then modify to use physical rear cameras (if possible).
